# Computing the number of terms in an $n$-fold finite sum with restriction that at least one index differs from all the others

Tags: summation, random-variables, independence, multinomial-coefficients

I wish to compute the sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_{2k}=1}^n1
\end{align}
with restriction that at least for one fixed index $i_s$ we have $i_s\neq i_r$ if $r\neq s$.

This arises from trying to count the number of terms that are zero in the following expectation for  centred i.i.d random variables $X_i$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^{2k}=\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_{2k}=1}^n\mathbb{E}(\prod_{s=1}^{2k}X_{i_s})
\end{align*}
or equivalently
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)^{2k}=\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=1,2,\dots,n}}\binom{2k}{k_1,k_2,\dots k_n}X_i^{k_1}X_2^{k_2}\dots X_n^{k_n}.
\end{align*}
Thus equivalently I could also compute
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{1+k_2+\dots+k_n=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=2,\dots,n}}&\binom{2k}{1,k_2,\dots k_n}+\sum_{\substack{k_1+1+\dots+k_n=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=1,3,\dots,n}}\binom{2k}{k_1,1,\dots k_n}+\dots \\
&+\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+\dots+1=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=1,2,\dots,n-1}}\binom{2k}{k_1,k_2,\dots 1},
\end{align*}
but apart from obvious symmetry in the terms I don't know how to start evaluating this either.

Edit. As I have commented below what I'm actually after is the sum

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=2k} \\ \,\,\,\, \text{even partitions}}\binom{2k}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n}.
\end{align*}

The lowest sum above in my original question is actually computable, but I don't think it is correct for the original question.

we know by taking $x_i=1$ for all $i$ in the multinomial theorem that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=m}\\ \,\,\,\,k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\geq 0}\binom{m}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n}=n^m.
\end{align*}
Also noting that
\begin{align*}
\binom{2k}{k_1,\dots,k_i=1,\dots,k_n}&=\binom{2k}{k_1=1,k_2,\dots,k_n}=\dfrac{(2k)!}{1!k_2!\dots k_n!}=2k\dfrac{(2k-1)!}{k_2!\dots k_n!} \\
&=2k\binom{2k-1}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{n-1}},
\end{align*}
where the last step is just a relabelling the indices. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{1+k_2+\dots+k_n=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=2,\dots,n}}&\binom{2k}{1,k_2,\dots k_n}+\sum_{\substack{k_1+1+\dots+k_n=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=1,3,\dots,n}}\binom{2k}{k_1,1,\dots k_n}+\dots \\
&+\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2+\dots+1=2k\\
k_i\geq0 \forall i=1,2,\dots,n-1}}\binom{2k}{k_1,k_2,\dots 1}=2kn(n-1)^{2k-1},
\end{align*}
which seems too large to be the correct answer to the original question.

Perhaps some inclusion-exclusion argument is needed here and also in the question of the even partitions.

For a fixed $m=2s-1<2k$ and $j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ we can make similar computation

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{k_1+\dots+k_j=m+\dots+k_n=2k}\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\geq 0}&\binom{2k}{k_1,\dots,k_j=m,\dots,k_n}\\
&=\dfrac{2k(2k-1)\dots(2k-m)}{m!}\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_+\dots+k_n=2k-m}\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\geq 0}\binom{2k-m}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{n-1}}\\
&=\dfrac{2k(2k-1)\dots(2k-m)}{m!}(n-1)^{2k-m} \\
&=\dfrac{2k(2k-1)\dots(2k-2s+1)}{(2s-1)!}(n-1)^{2k-2s+1}
\end{align*}

Now for each $s\leq k$ we get $n$ such terms, but we should sum over all $s$ with appropriate "weighting" to avoid overcounting or something like this.

Where does my reasoning go wrong here?

Comment: Actually I just realized that to count the terms that are zero in the expectation value I would need to count all the terms that have at least one odd power in them. However Since I think the question as it stands is still interesting in my opinion, I'll leave it as it is for now.

Comment: The question of the number of terms with only even powers is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166540/multinomial-theorem-number-of-elements-where-all-coefficients-have-even-powers). However the opening question is still open so I leave it as is.